# How to click on the element with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am automating a web module in google chrome browser by using selenium web driver. I have created a relative XPath of a web element to whom I want to click that but unfortunately, it is not working and giving me an exception that this XPath is not located on a web page. Dynamic XPath was not working as I have captured that one first, that's why I have created relative XPath.

**Selenium code:**

```
//Dashboard:
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sidebar\"]/section/ul/li[1]/a"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(ele).perform(); // Mover Hover     
WebElement ele2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sidebar\"]/section/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a"));
ele2.click(); // Click onto Weather
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement ele4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'pvExplorationHost')]//li[1]/div"));
ele4.click();
```

**HTML Code on Web page:**

```
<div class="textLabel" ng-click="disableClick || makeEditable()" title="Waffle Charts - All Variables">Waffle Charts - All Variables</div>
```

[enter image description here][1]

**Exception coming on Selenium:**

```
Only local connections are allowed.
Jul 04, 2018 2:15:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Test Passed!
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id, 'pvExplorationHost')]//li[1]/div"}
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'MACPK-WKS-0072', ip: '192.168.8.100', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '10'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa876..., userDataDir: C:\Users\MOMNA~1.ARS\AppDat...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 67.0.3396.99, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 2615a71e0f1b2d97c0611fc399cdda8b
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[contains(@id, 'pvExplorationHost')]//li[1]/div}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:317)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:419)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:309)
    at newpackage.DynamicXPath.main(DynamicXPath.java:74)
```

Please advise me I am over stuck here, As I am new to Selenium Web-Driver.

Comment: It seems the exception is not related to this piece of code. It refers to "{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id, 'pvExplorationHost')]//li[2]/div"} " but your example code lists an xpath with id "pvExplorationHost" and under that li[2].

Comment: Yes, by mistake i forgot to comment this piece of code. Check the exception now i have eidted in description

Comment: Ok. So it basically tells you the element is nowhere to be found. This usually means one of 2 things: 1) the xpath is incorrect and there is no such element. or 2) The element is not on the page YET when it tries to look for it. You then have to make the webdriver wait for it. There are many topics on that. Your code setting the implicit wait time does not do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks then which wait statement for explicit wait do I need to use. Please guide.

Comment: implicit waits are usually discouraged, however for quick testing it's useful. Look for Thread.sleep() . Explicit waits are the preferred choice for actual use. You have many conditions you can wait. Many tutorials can be found by a simple search, such as https://seleniumjava.com/2016/04/05/the-beginners-guide-to-explicit-waits/

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to target above mentioned Div, You can use this Xpath with Explicit wait.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@ng-click='disableClick || makeEditable()']")));
```

Comment: I tried by using your above trick as:  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@title = 'Waffle Charts - All Variables']")));
      
    WebElement ele4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@title = 'Waffle Charts - All Variables']"));
    ele4.click();

Comment: But got exception as: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@title = 'Waffle Charts - All Variables'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: @Mary Please debug the script, You will get where exactly script is Stuck.

Comment: Ok, i have also checked by increased the time upto 100 seconds but same exception poppped up.

Comment: Make sure you are targeting web element on correct page. I can see on your code, Page becoming change By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sidebar\"]/section/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a") here, So make sure you are not targeting element of existing or old page.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I resolved the issue actually there were embedded frames on the web page first i have switched onto that and then extarct the xpath as:

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@class, 'generic_iframe')]")));
Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 
'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed')]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Waffle Charts - All Variables')]")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the desired element is an [**Angular**](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.textLabel[title='Waffle Charts - All Variables']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='textLabel' and @title='Waffle Charts - All Variables'][contains(.,'Waffle Charts - All Variables')]"))).click();
  ```